# Ranger image preview not working in URXVT running Fish shell until I open an image in Feh

Tags: rxvt, fish, ranger

I recently started using the Fish shell, and after opening a new URXVT instance I cannot get image previews in Ranger until I open an image first (using feh, in my case). Once an image has been opened image previews start working, and remain working in that instance of URXVT. I did not have the same issue when using Bash in URXVT. I have the following settings in my Ranger rc.conf

```
set preview_images true
set preview_images_method w3m
set w3m_delay 0.02
set w3m_offset 0
```

I tried increasing the w3m_delay some, but it did not seem to make any difference. Any ideas/suggestions are appreciated.